# Issues upgrading EntityFrameworkCore from 5.0 to 6.0.14 (The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s)....)

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

my team has inherited a c# application where we have to make some modifications/updates, one of them is to ensure it works using EntityFrameworkCore 6 instead of 5.0. Currently we are using it to connect to an SQLite database.

First of all I'm going to put an overly simplified version of the code I'm having issues with:

Repository class:

```
public async Task AddAsync<T>(T entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    await _dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
}


public async Task<List<T>> GetListAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition = null, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null,
                                            bool asNoTracking = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    if (condition != null) query = query.Where(condition);
    if (includes != null) foreach (var expression in includes) query = query.Include(expression);
    if (asNoTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();
    return await query.AsSingleQuery().ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}


public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
}
```

Models:

```
public record MainEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public ICollection<RelatedEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }

    public MainEntity() { }
    public MainEntity(string id)
    {            
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public record RelatedEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }  // This is actually a foreign key to MainEntity.Id and it's the primary key of the table with 'CoId' property
    public string CoId { get; set; } 
}
```

Manager

```
        public async Task SaveStateDB(CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var repository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRepository>();
                lock (lockToSave)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var includes = new List<Expression<Func<MainEntity, object>>> { x => x.OtherEntities };
                        var Storage = repository.GetAsync(x => x.Id == id, includes, true, cancellation).Result;
                        bool isNew = false;
                        if (Storage == default)
                        {
                            Storage = new MainEntity(id);
                            isNew = true;
                        }
                        var OtherEntities = GetOtherEntities();
                        if (Storage.OtherEntities == null) Storage.OtherEntities = OtherEntities;
                        else
                        {
                            Storage.OtherEntities.Except(IoVariables).ForEach(x => repository.Delete(x));
                            OtherEntities.Except(Storage.OtherEntities).ForEach(x => Storage.OtherEntities.Add(x));
                        }
                      

                        if (isNew) repository.AddAsync(Storage, cancellation).Wait();
                        else repository.Update(Storage);

                        repository.SaveAsync(cancellation);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            repository.SaveAsync(cancellation);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            logger.LogError("--------------------" + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace + "--------------------");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

The system using EFCore 5 works 'perfectly fine', however, the moment I upgraded to the version 6 we have some issues.

When the database is empty everything works fine, the "repository.AddAsync(Storage, cancellation).Wait();" is being called and everything else is stored from scratch into the database. However, once the MainEntity is there, whenever we call again the 'SaveStateDB' and instead of the AddAsync we call the Update, then the issues appear.

The first one it appeared is that when we try to store some related entities to the database using the 'Update' method, appearing the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'Unable to track an entity of type 'RelatedEntity' because its primary key property 'Id' is null.'
```

Which it makes sense, cause as the error said, the related entity doesn't have an actual value on this property. I can solve this easily assignint the correct value to the property. But the first question I want to make is..why this worked on EFCore 5? The receiving data was exactly the same.

Once this issue is solved, now the update it seems to work, however, the code now fails when we are actually storing the new entities on the database using the 'SaveAsync' method (behind it only does a SaveChangesAsync), and the error appearing is:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'
```

This is the only point of the code accessing the database and no other process/user is messing with it, so the concurrency error is quite weird.

I found that I can solve this issue changing the Storage variable using 'false' on the method GetListAsync to avoid executing the 'AsNoTracking' on the query, however, I guess this was done to avoid performance issues (but I can't be sure) and I don't even know if this is a real solution or why it works this way.

So to summarize:

1. Why when the RelatedEntity had no Id could be stored on the database with EFCore5? (the data stored is correct, i guess it somehow assumes the id from the MainEntity?)
2. Why it only worked from scratch using the AddAsync and not the Update?
3. Why it fails when we use the 'AsNoTracking'? I would prefer to mantain it as I hope it was done like that for a valid reason. (Inherited project, we can't know why a lot of thigns where done like this).

Hope some can help me a bit! Thanks!

Comment: Don't mix async and sync code together. Use a `SemaphoreSlim` for async locking instead. ... though IMHO you should depend on optimistic concurrency instead.  EF Core generates an `update ... where key = ... and concurrency = ...` statement. If the query changes 0 rows, then the where clause didn't match anything, hence the slightly confusing message.

Comment: thanks about the SemaphoreSlim tip! It was something i had planned as all the .Result and .Wait were really annoying.